# Open onion links using selenium (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, proxy, tor

I'm trying to open .onion link with selenium (python3). But I'm getting same error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=dnsNotFound
```

Here is part of my code.

```
options = Options()
options.set_preference('profile', '<path>/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default')

options.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_remote_dns', False)


driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()), options=options)


driver.get('<link>.onion/auth/login')
```

I'm on Ubuntu 21.10. Going to 127.0.0.1:9050 in firefox gives info that tor is launched

UPD:
If I try to open tor connection check:

```
driver.get('http://check.torproject.org')
print(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'h1').text)
```

I get result:
`Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor`
So I assume the problem is with Onion link and get() method

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set remote dns to true so just replace this:

```
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_remote_dns', False)
```

to this:

```
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_remote_dns', True)
```

And you'll be able to open .onion links.